# How to navigate to App stack after login successfully using Redux?

Tags: react-native

I have a switch navigator

```
   // Add switch navigator
    export default createAppContainer(
        Config.Login.RequiredLogin
          ? createSwitchNavigator(
              {
                AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen, 
                App: DrawerNavigator, // App Stack
                Auth: AuthNavigator, // Auth Stack
              },
              {
                initialRouteName: "AuthLoading", 
              }
            )
          : DrawerNavigator
    );
```

During first app launch, it shows the "Auth" stack's login screen. After pressing the login button, it will call login API via fetch and update the redux user. When there's a user how should I navigate to "App" stack?

I've tried to place it in getDerivedStateFromProps but it's giving error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.props.navigation')

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.userToken !== nextProps.userToken) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("App");

      return {
        userToken: nextProps.userToken
      };
    }

    // Return null to indicate no change to state.
    return null;
  }
```

Should I place a flag in the render() and navigate there instead? Sorry I'm new in react native.

```
  render() {
    const { userToken } = this.props
    if(userToken){
      this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
    }


    ... other code for rendering login view
  }
```

What's the main purpose of getDerivedStateFromProps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getDerivedStateFromProps should be used to update the state with respect to newprops . it should not be used for redirect purpose . You should use [componentdidupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

**Try this**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  const { userToken } = this.props
    if(userToken){
      this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Just wondering what's the differences/benefits between putting this code in 1) render()  vs 2) componentDidUpdate()

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `NavigationService` as described in this document [navigating-without-navigation-prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)

Comment: I can access this.props.navigation in render() though...but it can't work in getDerivedStateFromProps.

Comment: This is static method. It doesn't have access to component instance. Besides, you can call `NavigationService.navigate("App")` right after you call login API.